# Disable Cross Origin Restriction in IIS 8

Tags: iis, cors, iis-8, same-origin-policy, cross-origin-read-blocking

I need to disable cross origin restriction in my web site temporarily.

[image]

Anybody know how to disable cross origin retriction in IIS 8 ? I dont get a "Properties" option when i right click on my site. Also couldn't locate a HTTP Headers tab.

[image]

Comment: It can be disabled. But you need install [CORS](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) on IIS first, then [configure the web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) to allow host origins.

Answer (score 1):

It is the browsers that require proper CORS headers to be responded by web servers, so you cannot "disable cross origin restriction in IIS". Read the CORS error message once again and you should see what it actually means.

The right way to resolve such errors is to configure your web apps on IIS to generate CORS headers in responses. It heavily depends on the framework you use (ASP.NET/PHP or others) so please refer to their documentation.

If you just want an easy way out, like @BruceZhang suggested in the comment, you can install IIS CORS module to generate CORS headers.

Answer (score -1):

You need just need your site to send the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the value `*` to "turn off" [CORs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/) (well allow any origin).

*(Obviously dont do this on a production site unless its just temporary/debugging :)*

You can add custom HTTP headers via the IIS Manager GUI(its called "HTTP Response Headers" - on screenshot), or web.config ([customHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/) element) or from your application.